# Salesforce Custom Navigation

Tags: lightning-apps, navigation, lightning-tabset

Currently we have to create our apps with set of `Tabs` but I would like to have total control over where these tabs should display e.g; on right side of application. Add sub Tabs under main tab etc etc. But it seems it's not possible in salesforce? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you update your question with more details? Why not use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset in a custom component?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. But you can customize with lightning pages, by adding lightning components as per your requirement. Even you can have your Template to that page as per requirement.
Note:the above comes under a single tab, under that tab page is displayed.